# Where do I find dojo module locations?

Tags: dojo, js-amd

Seems like no one is having this problem but me, but where does one find the module location and documentation for the various Dojo modules? For example, the examples give the location of the xhr module at `dojo/_base/xhr`, but upon scouring the documentation I can't find anything about the xhr module or any module really. Only  way to find it is google but that seems counter productive for learning, well, anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [xhr documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/_base/xhr.html) is available as part of the [Dojo reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/) under the Documentation section of Dojo's site.  The landing pages could be laid out a lot better.  Your suggestions are welcome.  There's a link for feedback at the bottom of most documentation pages.

Comment: Definitely a plus, thank you for that link. The API reference is essentially useless for this sort of thing, it seems. I'll comb through that, thanks!

Comment: also try the [beta reference guide](http://staging.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/) for the 1.8 release.  They've improved it a bit.

Comment: In my experience, the comments on dojo source code are really excellent, so I'll just open a console and type the function name to check. Of course, this isn't so easy for people who have (wisely) migrated to AMD...

Comment: Can't you just do require("dojo/some/module").method?